# Generate c# service skeleton from service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I created a service reference with VS to a soap service. Now the server is offline and I would like to build a simple server for testing purposes. I've already tried wsdl.exe with the wsdl file but didn't work because it couldn't reach the server.

Is there any simple way to acheive this? Of course, I'm not expecting any business logic to be magically created, just the structures and empty methods. Then I'll make it respond with dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder [project]\ServiceReferences\[service reference name] you'll find two files: one .wsdl and other .xsd

The xsd file contains the information that wsdl.exe was trying to get online. So running:

```
wsdl /language:CS /serverInterface file.wsdl file.xsd
```

will create the interface for the service. Then, create a new Wsdl Service Library project, add the interface (the new .cs file found in the same folder than wsdl.exe) and add the correct attributes to the interface, methods and data objects (if there's any).

Creating the service class is easy now that you have the interface.